# Why does my code enter into an infinite loop at the initial nested for loop on execution?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing

This code I am trying to right is for the Attribute parser question for the C++ program on Hackerrank.
The code is not complete yet as I am passing into this dreadful infinite loop again and again as im not able to solve it.

The code:

```
struct tag{
    char name[100];
    char att[100][100];
    char val[100][100];
};

int main(){

    tag tags[100];
    char line[200];
    int n,q;
    cin>>n>>q;

    int a,b,c,flag;
    a=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin.getline(line,200);

        b=c=flag=0;

        int j;
        if(flag==0){
            for(j=1;line[j]!=' '||line[j]!='>';j++)
               {tags[a].name[j]=line[j];
                cout<<"!";
                }
            flag=1;
        }
        else if(flag==1){
            while(line[j]!='>'){
                for(j+=1,c=0;line[j]!=' '||line[j]!='=';j++,c++){
                    tags[a].att[b][c]=line[j];
                }
                while(line[j]!='"')
                    j++;

                for(j+=1,c=0;line[j]!='\"';j++,c++){
                    tags[a].val[b][c]=line[j];
                }
                b++;
            }
            a++;
        }
    }

    cout<< tags[0].name[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I'm new to Coding and all. Constructive Criticism will be appreciated :))

Comment: Give variables meaningful names. For example, `flag` doesn't tell the reader what that variable does. As a guess (and the need to guess illustrates the problem), it might be `first_time`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this condition:

```
line[j]!=' ' || line[j]!='>'
```

for any value of `line[j]`, one of the conditions of the disjunction will be true. This leads to an infinite loop.

You are looking for:

```
line[j]!=' ' && line[j]!='>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=1;line[j]!=' '||line[j]!='>';j++)
```

should be

```
for(j=1;line[j]!=' '&& line[j]!='>';j++)
```

Also you never be get inside of else section, because at start of iteration you are setting flag==0 and if(flag==0) always be true

Comment: But I am setting the flag to be 1 in the function where I check flag==0. So, I guess I would be able to enter the else block.

Comment: you are setting flag=1, its okay. But at the start of next iteration flag will again initialize to 0 ( b=c=flag=0; ), before checking the condition. Let me know if your else block is executing with this change.

Comment: Yeah that is intentional because I want to run it once starting of every iteration